# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 20 1 5 5, expected input[10, 3, 224, 224] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Tags: pytorch

my input image is with 3 channels :

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

how can I update this model to be adequate with my input shape.

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen that when the neural network propagates forward, an error occurs in this sentence：

```
x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
```

The reason for the error is that the number of dimensions entered into Conv2d does not match. By querying the introduction of [Conv2d in the official document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d) , we can see that the input dimension of Conv2d is determined by the first parameter.

In the previous code, the parameter is 1. If you want to match the entered dimension, you should change it to 3.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 20, 5, 1)
```

After modification, you can see that no error will be reported and your problem has been successfully solved.

---

I'm sorry that I didn't pay attention to this point at that time. You can use the built-in debug function of the ide to conduct single-step debugging, and you can easily see the contents of variables.
I used the debug function to debug and found that there was an error in

```
 x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)
```

You can break points in this line of code or output x.shape. You can see the shape of x before this line:

```
torch.Size([4, 50, 53, 53])
```

The view function means to reset the shape of the tensor, so the statement wants to set the shape of the tensor to [b, 50 * 53, * 53], so you should change the statement to:

```
x = x.view(-1, 50*53*53)
```

And the statement should be modified

```
 self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
```

to

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(50*53*53, 500)
```

Then modify the overall code as:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(50*53*53, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 50*53*53)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Comment: If I make your proposition, I find this error `x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)`
`RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 800]' is invalid for input of size 1404500`

Comment: @seni I change the answer,you can look it